# Get filepath of imageview resource and upload to server

Tags: php, android, postgresql

In my application, The user can upload their profile photo, and it will change the image view to their photo. I need to store the file path in a variable. How is this possible?

here is the code:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

And then the result changes the profile IMAGE VIEW to the selected image from their phone.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri bitmapUri = data.getData();

        try {

            Bitmap b = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), bitmapUri);
            profile.setImageBitmap(b);
            submit.setEnabled(true);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

After this, I need to send it through to my ApiConnector class (connects with database - runs through PHP to get to database) and upload it to the server.

here is the code to upload to the server so far (not accounting that the one parameter is the image):
In the upload class:

```
private class SignUpForProfile extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector, Long, JSONArray> {
    User user = User.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {
        return params[0].signupForProfile(user.getId(), firstname.getText().toString(), lastname.getText().toString(), age.getText().toString(), profileURL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
        done(jsonArray);
    }
}
```

In the ApiConnector class:

```
public JSONArray signupForProfile(String id, String firstname, String lastname, String age, String pic) {
    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",id));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname",firstname));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname",lastname));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age",age));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pic_large",pic));
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL + "create_profile.php");
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    if(httpEntity != null) {
        try {
            String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

I am using Postgresql - for what it is worth.

Any help with this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Storing a file path is the same as storing any other data. You can use Shared Preferences, or store it in a database on the phone. Here are all the options: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

If you are trying to pass the file path to the second activity just use `extras` like so:

```
filePath = "my/file/path.jpg"
Intent i = new Intent(this, ToClass.class);
i.putExtra("filePath", filePath);
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the second activity you do:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String easyPuzzle = intent.getExtras().getString("filePath");
```

Comment: I need to pass the entire image on to the next activity and upload it, is it possible with just storing the file path in shared prefs and try upload the image in the second activity?

Comment: @user3241507 If you are trying to pass the file path to the second activity then you can simply use intents. See edit